# Comparing the length of two strings with Ruby

Tags: ruby, string-length

Define a method called `first_longer_than_second` with a parameter called `first` and another called `second`. The method will return `true` if the `first` word passed in is greater than or equal to the length of the `second` word. It returns false otherwise. Here's how the method would be called and the expected return:

This is what I have:

```
def first_longer_than_second(first, second)
   if first.length >= second.length
     puts true
   else
     puts false
   end
end
```

I am getting errors and I not sure why.

Comment: could you please post what errors you get?

Comment: Please format your code correctly - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers

Comment: shot in the dark without knowing what your errors are, but `puts` prints a line and then returns `nil`, which isn't what it sounds like your method is supposed to do...

Answer (score 2):

Ruby comparison operators like `>=` return boolean values naturally. You don't need to use a conditional, and you almost never want to return string equivalents of `true` and `false`. Also, Ruby convention is to use a question mark in the name of methods that return boolean values.

For this kind of method, Ruby lets us write this:

```
def first_longer_than_second?(first, second)
  first.length >= second.length
end
```

Then you can call the method like this:

```
>> first_longer_than_second?('hello', 'sir')
=> true
```

Note that the method name is somewhat confusing since it returns true if `first` is the same length as `second`. You might consider renaming the method as appropriate. Names do matter!